# Issue with access inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I keep receiving a syntax error on this particular statement.

```
SELECT tbl1.ProjectID, tbl1.EntryDate AS StartDate, tbl2.EntryDate AS EndDate, 
(tbl3.ChecklistDayMax - tbl3.ChecklistDayMin + 1) AS DaysAllotted, 
(SELECT ProjectPriority FROM project_master WHERE ProjectID = tbl1.ProjectID) AS Priority,
tbl3.MilestoneName,
IIF(Priority = 1, tbl3.BonusDaysFH, 
IIF(Priority = 2, tbl3.BonusDaysFM, 
IIF(Priority = 3, tbl3.BonusDaysFL))) AS BonusDaysAllotted
FROM (((checklist_entries AS tbl1
INNER JOIN checklist_entries AS tbl2 ON tbl1.ProjectID = tbl2.ProjectID)
INNER JOIN milestone_def AS tbl3 ON [@milestoneID] = milestone_def.MilestoneDefID)
INNER JOIN project_active_status AS tbl4 ON tbl1.ProjectID = project_active_status.ProjectID)
WHERE tbl1.ChecklistDay = tbl3.ChecklistDayMin
AND tbl2.ChecklistDay = tbl3.ChecklistDayMax
AND tbl4.ProjectIsOpen = FALSE;
```

The error says **Syntax Error In Join Operation** and then it highlights milestone_def right after the 2nd INNER JOIN. Funny thing is, if I switch this line...

```
INNER JOIN milestone_def AS tbl3 ON [@milestoneID] = milestone_def.MilestoneDefID)
```

with this line...

```
INNER JOIN milestone_def AS tbl3 ON [@milestoneID] = tbl3.MilestoneDefID)
```

I get the error **Join Expression Not Supported** and then it highlights...

```
[@milestoneID] = tbl3.MilestoneDefID)
```

But as you can see, in the first join...

```
INNER JOIN checklist_entries AS tbl2 ON tbl1.ProjectID = tbl2.ProjectID
```

I name it tbl2 and then use tbl2.ProjectID and the expression works just fine. Ultimately, I need to get this to work, regardless how how I name these things.

[@milestoneID] is a parameter passed into the query to match milestone_def.MilestoneDefID

Comment: The question title is "too loud".

Comment: What is `[@milestoneID]` is it from a table? What table is it from?  Try placing the correct table alias before that column and then use `tbl3.MilestoneDefID` with the other column in the join.

Comment: It is a parameter that is passed into the query.

Comment: I had a similar error a couple of days ago in simple sum from 2 tables that had to be stored in a third table. After a looong search, i learned that access doesn't support dynamic subquerries. The only solution i found (and i agree it isn't optimal and not even efficient) was to create intermediate queries that do what i need and store the results in new tables. once i have all the intermediate tables i need, then i do a join between them. To make the process more efficient, I created a macro that calls the different querries in order and that calls a querry to delete the data in temp tables

Comment: @user1066133 Does `milestone_def` actually JOIN to any of the other tables in your query?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are all those parentheses around the `INNER JOIN` clauses required by Access's SQL parser? They're certainly not necessary in standard SQL.

Comment: [Long comments deleted in favour of an answer for readability, even if it turns out to be wrong/irrelevant.] `tbl3` is a **really bad** alias, by the way - aliases are like variable names, and should be chosen with similar care; the usual convention is to abbreviate the table name, e.g. `milestone_def as md`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Expanded from comments.] This is just a hunch, as I don't have access to Access (ha ha), but your query currently specifies an `INNER JOIN` that doesn't actually relate the table to the rest of the query:

```
... 
INNER JOIN milestone_def AS tbl3
ON [@milestoneID] = milestone_def.MilestoneDefID
...
```

The `ON` clause references only an external variable, so isn't relevant to the `JOIN` operation, making this effectively a `CROSS JOIN` with a separate `WHERE` condition:

```
... 
CROSS JOIN milestone_def AS tbl3
...
WHERE [@milestoneID] = milestone_def.MilestoneDefID
...
```

Looking at the bottom of your query, you have the actual join conditions for this table in the `WHERE` clause; these should be swapped into the `ON` clause, so that it actually specifies the `INNER JOIN` condition:

```
... 
INNER JOIN milestone_def AS tbl3
ON tbl1.ChecklistDay = tbl3.ChecklistDayMin
AND tbl2.ChecklistDay = tbl3.ChecklistDayMax
...
WHERE [@milestoneID] = milestone_def.MilestoneDefID
...
```

It's certainly more logical that way, and it will possibly solve the problem Access's parser is having understanding your query.

Comment: The last statement is clearer and did work for me. Only thing I had to change was the WHERE [@milestoneID] = tbl3.MilestoneDefID. Otherwise the query asked for two parameters and came back with more records than it should have. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem is with the joins, you would be wise to investigate the issue with a simpler query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    ((checklist_entries AS tbl1
    INNER JOIN checklist_entries AS tbl2
    ON tbl1.ProjectID = tbl2.ProjectID)
    INNER JOIN milestone_def AS tbl3
    ON [@milestoneID] = milestone_def.MilestoneDefID)
    INNER JOIN project_active_status AS tbl4
    ON tbl1.ProjectID = project_active_status.ProjectID
```

Notice you have aliased the table names.  Therefore you must use those aliases instead of the table names in the `ON` clauses.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    ((checklist_entries AS tbl1
    INNER JOIN checklist_entries AS tbl2
    ON tbl1.ProjectID = tbl2.ProjectID)
    INNER JOIN milestone_def AS tbl3
    ON tbl1.[@milestoneID] = tbl3.MilestoneDefID)
    INNER JOIN project_active_status AS tbl4
    ON tbl1.ProjectID = tbl4.ProjectID
```

I don't know what `[@milestoneID]` is or where it comes from.  My best guess is it's a field in `checklist_entries`, so I qualified it with the `tbl1` alias.

Answer (score -1):

I think HansUp's answer is pointing you in the right direction. One other thing that I noticed is that you have a series of three nested IIFs and the final one only has a test and a true but is missing the false parameter. I thought that all three were compulsory.